# SQL inner join duplicates

Tags: sql, duplicates, inner-join, ssms

The query returns duplicates on columns when adding the third table to the query

**TABLE A**
A.AccId
A.AccNr
A.EntId

**TABLE B**
B.EntName
B.EntId

**TABLE C**
C.AccNr
C.CustomerNr

```
SELECT A.AccID, A.AccNr, A.EntId, B.EntName, B.EntId, C.AccNr,C.CustomerNr, C.EntName
FROM ((Cat.dbo.A
INNER JOIN Cat.dbo.B ON A.EntId = B.EntId)
INNER JOIN Dog.dbo.C ON B.EntName = C.EntName
```

Comment: I believe that `GROUP BY` will be your solution

Comment: i don't see `EntName` column in your table `c`

Comment: specify the relationships between  the tables

Comment: What is wrong in there? What is the question really? I assume you meant B.EntId = C.EntID. If those names are what I guessed then you have a bad data design.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Your query needs to be updated first. I dont see EntName column in Table C.

There is a possibility of duplicates, if there are many rows matching in Table C  , rows from Table A & Table B are repeated while joining with Table C.

If there are many records matching for EntName in C, then you will have duplicates. if you don't want duplicate, you have to apply DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.AccID, A.AccNr, A.EntId, B.EntName, B.EntId, C.AccNr,C.CustomerNr
FROM Cat.dbo.Accounts
INNER JOIN Cat.dbo.B ON A.EntId = B.EntId
INNER JOIN Dog.dbo.C ON B.EntName = C.EntName
```

Or if duplicates are due to duplicate records in Table C, you can filter them out before JOIN.

```
SELECT A.AccID, A.AccNr, A.EntId, B.EntName, B.EntId, C.AccNr,C.CustomerNr
FROM Cat.dbo.Accounts
INNER JOIN Cat.dbo.B ON A.EntId = B.EntId
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT CustomerNr, EntName FROM Dog.dbo.C) AS C ON B.EntName = C.EntName;
```

Comment: I have used disctint it still returns same results